# How can I disconnect my profile from a dead OSX Server?

Tags: user-account, osx-server, server.app

I had a mac mini server with OSX server. The profile I user on my iMac was created on the server, and some groups where on the server, which was also a server for TM backups. For now, the user on the iMac is Admin, Managed, Mobile.
The server died recently (in fact, with the different downgrades of the server App by Apple, at the end it was just serving files), but the user on the iMac is still locked to it.

For example, I can't change password anymore...

What can I do to transform the managed account into a normal independent account on the iMac?

Comment: Before attempting to convert the account to local, I'd recommend 1) making sure you have a good backup, and 2) creating another admin account. Some methods can delete the user account and files if you do it slightly wrong, so having a backup -- both of the files and the admin account -- is a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to unbind your account from the active directory by going to
System Preferences -> Users & Grops -> Login Items -> Network Account Server -> Open Directory Utility -> Active Directory -> Unbind.

> [Apple official documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/unbind-from-a-server-diruda43d3f4/mac)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the solution from Apple (not really in System Preferences, but Directory Utility.app), and it shows me that Active Directory is already unbound, I have "Active directory domain" in blank, and the button is labeled Bind..., not Unbind